# I am getting a nil value even if i give a url variable a value, so i want to know what am i doing wrong?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I just created a app which simply downloads a pdf file from a url, save it to cachesDirectory and then display it in a pdfView using SwiftUI, refer to my comments in body property to check whats i am doing wrong

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @State var documentURL: URL?
        @State var ispresented: Bool = false

    func downloadFile(completion: @escaping (URL)->Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_tutorial.pdf") else { return }
       let task =  URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (localURL, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let docsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
                let destinationPath = docsPath.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
                try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationPath)
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: localURL!, to: destinationPath)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(destinationPath) }
                    
                } catch {
                    print("Error copying:\(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    downloadFile { localUrl in
                        print("Closure url:\(localUrl)")

// here i am getting valid localUrl means i can see and open the downloaded file in finder when i follow the url in HardDisk 

                        self.documentUrl = localUrl
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(localUrl, forKey: "url")
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Start Downloading")
                    })
                    Button("Open PDFView") {
                        ispresented.toggle()
                    }
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $ispresented, content: {
                    PDFKitRepresentableView(url: documentURL!)

// here i am getting error that documentURL is nil

                    
                })
     }
```

So, What Am i doing wrong here ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue caused by downloadFile making an asynchronous call, I am not sure exactly why it doesn't work but I managed to get it to work with the below solution where I skipped the completion handler and assigned the documentsUrl property inside the URLSession closure instead

So the `do` clause is changed to

```
do {
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: localURL!, to: destinationPath)
    documentUrl = destinationPath
}
```

To make the UI clearer I added a `disabled` operator to the second button so you can't click it until the file has been downloaded

```
Button("Open PDFView") {
    ispresented.toggle()
}.disabled(documentUrl == nil)
```

Note that you can of course keep the closure if you want to do other stuff there but it wasn't needed for this solution

Comment: I tried your solution but its still crashing because of that documentURL found nil when opening sheet, is this a bug ?

Comment: Did you also add .disabled for the button?

Comment: Yes, now it worked thanks a lot, can you tell me the reason behind it

Comment: @AdityaInamdar No I don't know the reason for this behaviour